# I have a transparent image to use in my html code in vscode but when I open it with live server the image doesn't get transparent

Tags: html, responsive-images

please help me in understanding my error of the code, in why the transparent images with .png extension are not getting transparent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>First Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>IMAGES:</h1>
    <br>
    <p><b>1</b></p><br>
    <img src="https://www.pinpng.com/pngs/m/77-779483_anime-guy-wolf-deity-anime-pics-cute-boys.png" alt="Image not found">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image isn't with a transparent background. It's with a 'transparent' grid background, so it looks/fakes like it's transparent but it isn't.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded the file on the [display page](https://www.pinpng.com/picture/bxihhh_anime-guy-wolf-deity-anime-pics-cute-boys/). This is a JPEG file with a `.png` extension.

If you press the `Free Download` button you get a PNG with transparency